# requirement of ellipticity property in definning viscosity solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Why it is important to require ellipticity condition in defining the notion of viscosity solution of degenerate elliptic or parabolic pde.

Answer (score 1):

Without ellipticity, you don't have a comparison principle, and the entire idea of viscosity solutions is to compare against suitable continuous functions.